# Python script as windows service

Tags: python

I am trying to launch my python script as windows service in Windows 10. To do this I followed tons of guides online, but I mostly encounter `Access denied 5.` or `The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion` Here is how I launched it:

```
import time
import requests
import pythoncom
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    # you can NET START/STOP the service by the following name
    _svc_name_ = "Smartlab_heater"
    # this text shows up as the service name in the Service
    _svc_display_name_ = "Smartlab_heater"
    # this text shows up as the description in the SCM
    _svc_description_ = "This service gets data from Siemens server and sends it to Smartlab server"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        # create an event to listen for stop requests on
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    # called when we're being shut down 
    def SvcStop(self):
        # tell the SCM we're shutting down 
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        # fire the stop event  
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    #CUSTOM FUNCTIONS HERE

    # core logic of the service 
    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                            servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                            (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.timeout = 20000     #20 seconds
        # This is how long the service will wait to run / refresh itself (see script below)a

        rc = None

        # if the stop event hasn't been fired keep looping  
        while True:
            # Wait for service stop signal, if I timeout, loop again
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
            # Check to see if self.hWaitStop happened
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                # Stop signal encountered
                servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("SomeShortNameVersion - STOPPED!")  #For Event Log
                break
            else:
                #MY CODE HERE

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

I tried to simply launch it like this `C:Loc\of\script>python script.py install`

When I tried to start it I got Access denied. Then I read somewhere that it might be, because I did not define username and password, thus I tried: `C:Loc\of\script>python script.py install --username <my user name> -- password`.(Note: Pass is empty because I don't use 1).

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I always use nssm (https://nssm.cc/) for starting my Python programs as a windows service. Much less headaches. You could try to let your service be run as the local "system" account.

Comment: Will check nssm.cc . May i just ask right away; Do I need to tweak my script in any way in order to run it (like example above)?